# Ectracting some content between two words in R

Tags: regex, r

If this is the test string -

```
alt="mass |36 grams\nserving volume | 63 mL (milliliters)\nserving density | 0.57 g\/cm^3 (grams per cubic centimeter)" title="mass | 36 grams.

\btitle="mass| \b.*+\s*+\K.*(?=serving volume\b)
```

This is my code but it does not return what is required.
Then how to extract 36 grams from this text?

It would be great if someone could share a link from where I can learn regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gsub('mass \\|([0-9]* [A-Za-z]*).*', '\\1', alt)
[1] "36 grams"
```

To exclude the unit:

```
gsub('mass \\|([0-9]*).*', '\\1', alt)
[1] "36"
```

Careful with the extra space, it will be captured too. This is not what you want:

```
gsub('mass \\|([0-9]* ).*', '\\1', alt)
[1] "36 "
```

Comment: Done Thanks Pierre Lafortune 
I wanted to extract only 36 
gsub('mass \\|([0-9]* ).*', '\\1', alt) It works with this

Comment: Glad it helped : ) Be careful with your edit, it looks like you kept a space after `[0-9]*`. The regex will keep the space and potentially create problems later with the trailing space. See the example.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you gave this will work, but depending on what you want to do you might need something more general:

```
alt<-"mass |36 grams\nserving volume | 63 mL (milliliters)\nserving density | 0.57 g/cm^3 (grams per cubic centimeter)"
gsub(".*\\|([0-9]+ gram).*","\\1",alt)
[1] "36 gram"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with:

```
/mass \|([a-zA-Z-0-9\s]+)\sserving volume/
```